# Mobile site in landscape wont scroll down

Tags: html, css, image

So we have a mobile website where we are using image mapping to create links etc. We are having a problem when device is in landscape we cant scroll down to see this full image. The image is 640X960. We're testing on a Galaxy S4.

### HTML

```
<img src="mobilelandscape.png" usemap="#Mapland" border="0" class = "landscape"  />
<map name="Mapland" id="Mapland">
  <area shape="rect" coords="532,286,879,468" href="contact.php" alt="Contact Us" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="398,497,930,685" href="index.php" alt="My account" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="382,696,907,870" href="newcust.php" alt="New Customers" />
</map>
```

### css

```
.landscape{
    display:block;  
    width:100%;
}

body{
    overflow:auto
}
```

Basically when the image fits to screen, it will not show the whole image, just the top part and the body seems to cut off the rest, there is no way to scroll down and see the remainder of the image, we have tried everything from not setting the image height to `height:100%`, we can't seem to find anything that addresses this specific issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: need more detail... any divs involved or anything? Maybe some more of you're HTML will help...

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to set the height of an image.

Example:

```
$('#thingYouAreHavingIssuesWith').css({
    'height' : $(window).height()
});
```